# The Beast Shall Render Your Soul

Tags: riddle

This is a poem with a wandering scheme about a potentially deadly force. Can you answer the questions posed?

> [REDACTED] is powerful, reliant, and tall
>   He performs every day for the plesaure of all
>   He towers above the gawkers below
>   Who've come to enjoy his regular show
>   We've found now, in fact, routine is rather
>   Bimodal in form meaning you sometimes gather
>   For sixty or ninety minutes before
>   He starts up his act lasting one minute four
>   At the most but sometimes it's short
>   Ninety seconds - abort
>
> He's not safe to get near though he means no harm
>   His own strength betrays him - he carries no arms
>   His father was Washburn who named him quite aptly
>   Although his performance is not quite the acme
>   His brother wins that title though he was named first
>   Not jealous a bit, though, as both quench the thirst
>   Of travelers seeking adventure and grandeur
>   Ironic a bit, given permanent tenure
>   He's a prisoner, see, and can never leave
>   But cry not for him. As a nation we've
>   Formed quite a home surrounding all sides
>   Of this giant whose entertainment provides
>   Joy for all the visitors who
>   Have come here again to view
>   The wonders provided
>   And all, breath bated,
>   Await the show
>   Do you know
>   the right
>   site?
>
> ANSWER NOW, FOOL, 'FORE HIS ANGER EXPLODES
>   AND UNLEASHES POWER HE'S STORED DOWN BELOW
>   HIS ENERGY'S GREAT AND POTENTIAL MIGHTY
>   HE'S TRAPPED HERE FOREVER HANDING OUT DEATHBLOWS
>   IF YOU WANDER TOO CLOSE YOUR FLESH SHALL BE RENDERED
>   FROM MORTAL COIL SO SOFT AND SO TENDER
>   FEAR HIM, YOU MORTAL, LEST YOUR CASUAL STRAYING
>   RELINQUISH YOUR SOUL TO HIS BEASTLY BLENDER
>   TELL ME HIS NAME AND THE NAME OF HIS HOME.
>   WHY IS HE TRAPPED AND CAN NEVER ROAM?
>   TELL ME THIS QUICKLY OR YOUR SOUL I SHALL HARVEST
>   AND BURY WITHIN THE BEAST'S CATACOMB

Comment: After the first verse I was sure it was going to be a clock (the "act" being chiming). I tried to search for a famous clockmaker named Washburn, couldn't find one, and gave up.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The beast's name is

> [Old Faithful](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Old_Faithful)

The first paragraph basically explains that it's a

> geyser

that "performs" at a regular interval. After that, it tells about [Washburn](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Henry_D._Washburn) naming it. Its "brother" is probably [Steamboat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steamboat_Geyser), the largest one of its kind. There's a lot of stuff talking about heat and water, which are self evident once you know the answer.

To literally answer the questions posed:

- Do you know the right site?

> Yellowstone National Park, Wyoming, United States

- WHY IS HE TRAPPED AND CAN NEVER ROAM?

> Two possible answers. 1) It's a geyser. They don't really move. 2) According to Wikipedia, it "*...is not connected to any other thermal features of the Upper Geyser Basin.*" So, it's isolated from other geysers, etc.

Comment: So... Too many clues to last very long. I had fun writing it, though! Do you see any areas to improve? (That doesn't mean the same thing as making it harder, mind you.)

Comment: Oh I quite liked it really. The wording is nice. A bit easy, but that could also be because I'm familiar with it (it's just one of those things you learn about growing up in the US). I don't know if it would be for someone from elsewhere. There *are* a lot of clues pointing to the general thing, but Washburn gives the specifics away to anyone with internet access.

Comment: @EngineerToast General riddley advice: try not to make one clue that gives away the answer much more easily than any of the others (here, Washburn). Specific quibble: how can something last one minute four (64 seconds) at the most but sometimes be as short as 90 seconds? :-D

Comment: @randal'thor Unless "one minute four" means five minutes (which *is* a bit odd). Wiki says the time is between 1.5-5 minutes.

Comment: @randal'thor The time bit was a bit forced to make the rhythm and rhyme work. Also, good advice on Washburn. I had hoped it would be a verification check and not a total giveaway. I'll consider dropping such specific items in the future.

Comment: @Geobits What about "The act starts and lasts one minute plus four" Any better or same weirdness? Is it better as "one minute *and* four"?

Comment: If you want to preserve syllable count, maybe "starting his act, lasting one minute and four" or something similar. It shifts the pause in the rhythm a bit, but it reads fine to me.